# uint32_t to double with negative result not working

Tags: c, floating-point, negative-number, typecast-operator

I have a uint32_t that needs to be translated into a signed float or double.

I have tried converting to 2s compliment and divding by the resolution, but when I print the value, the negative sign is not shown, but the absolute value seems to be correct.

I converted to 2s compliment and adjusting resolution by by
(~a +1) / 10000000 and storing to a new double variable

However, the negative sign doesn't come through
For example,
0xB9EB02A8 converts to 11757806960 and is missing the minus sign.

Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


int main(void)
{
    double lat;
    uint32_t dataWord0 = 0xb9eb04f2;
    lat = (~dataWord0 + 1);
    printf("%f",lat);
}
```

Output:
1175780110
Should be: -1175780110 then the decimal place needs to be moved to the left by 7 places to show the correct value of -117.5780110

Comment: By definition, `uint32_t` holds only values >= 0. The question should be modified to clarify why negative results are expected after converting to `double`. It would be best to add a minimal self-contained reproducer code that demonstrates desired vs observed behavior.

Comment: (a) Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Show the code that did not work. Nobody can tell you what was wrong with the code if you do not show the code. (b) To convert a `uint32_t` named `a` to two’s complement, use `int32_t b; memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof b);`, where `memcpy` is declared in `<string.h>`.

Comment: Updated with sample code.

Comment: A [mre] is should have ready-to-compile code. It should not use undefined structures, and it should include the `#include` directives and declarations necessary to compile. I updated the question for you with suitable code.

Comment: Eric, unless you have the microcontroller that I do, having more code won't help.

Comment: When `int` and `unsigned int` are 32 bits, which is common in current C implementations, `~dataWord0 + 1` necessarily produces a nonnegative result. Since the type of `dataWord0` is `uint32_t`, the type of `~dataWord0` is also `uint32_t`, so it has no sign and is not negative. Adding `1` also produces a `uint32_t` result. To make it negative, you could convert it to `int` or `int32_t` and then apply `-`, as in `- (int) (~dataWord0 + 1)`. However, you would then have to guard against 0x80000000. But this is unnecessary. A method to convert to the two’s complement interpretation was given above.

Comment: @StevenLutz: I did not ask for more code. I asked for a [mre]. The code I put into the question is a [mre]: It is small, it demonstrates the problem, and it can be easily compiled and executed.

Comment: To get the two’s complement interpretation of the value, use `int32_t x; memcpy(&x, &rxFrame.dataWord0, sizeof x); val = x;`.

Comment: Thank you. Simply copying the data between the 2 variables as suggested worked.